# Match a URL with placeholders with a URL with filled placeholders

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, pattern-matching

I am trying to match two URLs, one with placeholders and one with filled placeholders in Angular with TypeScript.

**For Example**

URL *before* the placeholders are filled:

```
http://this/is/{placeholder1}/{placeholder2}/my/url?limit=10&offset=5
```

URL *after* the placeholders are filled:

```
http://this/is/100Banana/200Apple/my/url?limit=10&offset=5
```

The target is to match those two URLs with Regex and get a match. One of the problems is, that the placeholders could be filled with anything a URL allows.

The first attemp was to replace the placeholders with Regex like `[^/]+` before the Regex match. But that only works if the placeholders were at the end of the URL.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want a function/piece of code that compares 2 strings and if the first string is the URL with placeholders and the second one is URL with filled placeholders then those two will be considered equal?

Comment: Use `var regex1 = new RegExp('foo', 'g');` the `g` makes the search global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to match them then you don't need a regex. You can do it like this.

```js
const str1 = 'http://this/is/{placeholder1}/{placeholder2}/my/url?limit=10&offset=5';
const str2 = 'http://this/is/100Banana/200Apple/my/url?limit=10&offset=5';

// url1: url with placeholders
// url2: url with filled placeholders
const compareUrls = (url1, url2) => {
  const u1 = url1.split('/');
  const u2 = url2.split('/');

  if (u1.length !== u2.length) { return false; }

  for (let i = 0; i < u1.length; i++) {
    if (u1[i].startsWith('{placeholder')) { continue; }
    if (u1[i] !== u2[i]) { return false; }
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(compareUrls(str1, str2));
```

Comment: If the filled placeholder contains '/ ', this solution won't work

Comment: @Rak2018 I don't think so. Please provide specific example where this would fail.

Comment: Thank you very much @MatusDubrava!
With a small adjustment it seems to work. I just added all the possible placeholders to check against. For the future this function might get to complex, but for now it should do it.

I also tested with a url parameter that contains a forwad slash (/) character and like @Rak2018 mentioned, it does not macht anymore.